# Java: How to test on array equality?

Tags: java, arrays, equality

Why is the following code printing `"Different."`?

```java
boolean[][] a = { {false,true}, {true,false} };
boolean[][] b = { {false,true}, {true,false} };

if (Arrays.equals(a, b) || a == b)
    System.out.println("Equal.");
else
    System.out.println("Different.");
```

Comment: I would always test `a == b` first or not at all. If `equals` is true, the second expression should always be true.

Comment: The standard implementation starts with that check anyway, so I would personally leave it out.

Comment: It should only indicate that both give false.

Comment: @PeterLawrey actually, you mean that if == is true, then equals should be true.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

> ***Why is the following code printing `"Different."`?***

Because [`Arrays.equals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28boolean[],%20boolean[]%29) performs a *shallow* comparison. Since arrays inherit their `equals`-method from `Object`, an identity comparison will be performed for the inner arrays, which will fail, since `a` and `b` do not refer to the *same* arrays.

If you change to [`Arrays.deepEquals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29) it will print `"Equal."` as expected.

Comment: Documentation says to Array.equals: "Returns true if the two specified arrays of Objects are equal to one another. The two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal." So doesnt that mean a complete comparison...?

Comment: No, because the elements of `a` and `b` don't `equals(...)` each other. Try it out yourself: `a[0].equals(b[0])` and you'll see that it's false.

Comment: It would be better to check for `a == b` before calling `deepEquals`, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, it would be better to leave that redundancy out all together. (The standard implementation of `Arrays.equals` start with that check anyway.)

Comment: Note that Arrays.equals is adequate for single dimension arrays: in this example, Arrays.equals(a[0], b[0]) is true.

Answer (score 17):

It's really not obvious.

First of all, the `==` operator just compare two pointers. Because `a` and `b` are distinct objects located at different memory addresses, `a == b` will return `false` (Hey, Java purists, I know that the `==` actually compare **object identities**. I'm just trying to be didactic).

Now let's take a look at the `equals()` implementation **of arrays**:

```
boolean[] c = new boolean[] { false, true, false };
boolean[] d = new boolean[] { false, true, false };

if (c.equals(d)) {
    System.out.println("Equals");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not equals");
}
```

That would print `Not equals` because **no array instance actually implements the `equals()` method**. So, when we call `<somearray>.equals(<otherarray>)` we are actually calling the `Object.equals()` method, which just compare two pointers.

That said, notice that your code is actually doing this:

```
boolean[] a0 = new boolean[] { false, true };
boolean[] a1 = new boolean[] { true, false };
boolean[] b0 = new boolean[] { false, true };
boolean[] b1 = new boolean[] { true, false };
boolean[][] a = new boolean[][] { a0, a1 };
boolean[][] b = new boolean[][] { b0, b1 };

if (Arrays.equals(a, b) || a == b)
    System.out.println("Equal.");
else
    System.out.println("Different.");
```

The `Arrays.equals(a, b)` will eventually call `a0.equals(b0)` which will return `false`. For this reason, `Arrays.equals(a, b)` will return `false` as well.

So your code will print `Different.` and we conclude that Java equality can be tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

Use Arrays.deepEquals() for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: lol, ty this was the answer i was looking for  a very long time

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean equal(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
        if (a == null) {
            return (b == null);
        }
        if (b == null) {
            return false;  // already know 'a' isn't null
        }
        if (a.length != b.length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (!Arrays.equals(a[i], b[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It´s not good practice to reimplement [`Arrays.deepEquals`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[]%29). The answers given so far cover good explanations and solutions.