# Why does this code in java print a reference instead the result of invoking the method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, reference, boolean

I am supposed to write a method that accepts 3 2-D arrays of This method should determine whether one of the matrices is the result of matrix addition of the other two.

```
public class Matrix {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int [][] a = {{5,2,3},{4,1,6},{0,7,2}};
        int [][] b = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{0,1,2}};
        int [][] t = {{6,4,6},{8,6,12},{0,8,4}};
        System.out.println(add(a,b));
        System.out.println(check(a,b,t));
    }

    public static int [][] add(int[][]a,int[][]b){
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int[][] r = new int [3][3];
        while (i<a.length){
            r[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
                i++;
                j++;
        }
        return r;
    }
    public static boolean check(int[][]a,int[][]b,int[][]t){
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while(i<t.length){
            if(t==add(a,b))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The printing statement prints a reference rather than the return types of both methods. So why is this? TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: Are you sure you read that other question? It explains that when you print an array object in Java directly, you get something like (their example) `[I@3343c8b3`. If that's not what your problem is, then please clarify.

Comment: Trivial edit: "... accepts 3 2-D arrays of *type `int`*. This method..."

Comment: Oh, I guess you've got 2 different questions in there, and my proposed duplicate only answers one of them. Give me a moment, I'll try to find a duplicate for the other.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8051084/3004881) is a duplicate of your second question (by that I mean `check()`, with the printing of the result of `add()` being your "first question")

Comment: It's my problem. My printing is rather different. I am invoking a method in the print statement. and the Arrays.deepToString results in an error : can't find symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add` returns an array. Arrays in Java are objects, but they do not override the `toString()` method. When printing, you'd print their default `toString()` call, which is implemented by `Object` as `return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`.

Luckily, Java provides a utility in the form of [`java.util.Arrays.deepToString(Ojbect[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) to generate a more readable string output:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(add(a,b)));
```

EDIT:
Your `add` method is also wrong. Your code iterates `i` and `j` together, so it only sums the elements along the matrix's diagonal instead of adding all of them. You should use a nested loop instead:

```
public static int [][] add(int[][]a, int[][]b) {
    int[][] r = new int [3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            r[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Your `check` method, by the way, is also wrong - it attempts to compare the array itself instead of is elements:

```
public static boolean check(int[][]a, int[][]b, int[][]t) {
    int[][] r = add(a, b);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            if (r[i][j] != t[i][j]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! But it keeps telling me error: can't find symbol

Comment: You need to add `import java.util.Arrays` to your class

Comment: Yeahh!! It worked but not the output i was looking for.

Comment: {6,0,0}{0,6,0}{0,0,4} Was my output which isnt the result of their addition. Sorry for asking too much!!